# Design Pattern for custom Error handling in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I am new to Design pattern. Can any one suggest right design pattern for custom error handling in asp.net.

Not using any third party framework for Error handling.

Comment: Read SO thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763474/exception-handling-in-a-three-tier-asp-net-application and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676607/design-pattern-for-error-handling-in-asp-net-3-5-site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should use a couple:
1) [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for Logger that writes log throughout all application.
2) [IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) to create a loose coupled application.

PS:
You should not create your own wheel and use some excellent tools that are on common use today

**Logging:**
1) log4net - for logging and handling exceptions.
2) Enterprise Library Log - very nice and easy to use.

**IoC - Inversion of Control:**
1) Ninject - my favorite
2) Unity 
and many more.....
as you can see 
[here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx)